# Fetch data from same named two columns of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, codeigniter, join

I am trying to fetch data from 2 tables with a join query. Here I have 2 columns in 2 tables with same column name.

This is my query:

```
public function get_all_expenses()
{
        $this->db->select("*",'category.name as cat_name');
        $this->db->from('expense');
        $this->db->join('category','expense.cat_id = category.id');
        $this->db->join('users','expense.user_id = users.id');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query;
}
```

I can fetch data of 1 column of 1 table. But I can't fetch data of another column of another table. I am using CodeIgniter.

[image]

Comment: Which error do you get ??

Comment: Thanks @adeys. I am not getting any error. But I can't see column in result. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried left / right join ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the CodeIgniter documentation the database `select` method accept a single argument. The correct syntax for the select is then:

```
$this->db->select('*, category.name as cat_name');
```